# avoid code duplication in template functions used to distinguish between const and non-const

Tags: c++, templates, code-duplication

In writing a program, I've come up with a piece of code that I cannot manage to make code-duplication free.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Presenter{
    public:
        template <typename T>
            void addField(T& t){
                cout << "do something that could happen to modify t" << endl;
            }

        template <typename T>
            void addField(const T& t){
                cout << "do something that cannot possibly happen to modify t" << endl;
            }
};

class Presented{
    public:
        Presented() : a(0), b(0.) {}
        void bind(Presenter& p){
            p.addField(a);
            p.addField(b);
            //...
        }
        void bind(Presenter& p) const {
            p.addField(a);
            p.addField(b);
            //...
        }
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
        //...
};

int main() {
    Presenter presenter;
    Presented p1;
    const Presented p2;
    p1.bind(presenter);
    p2.bind(presenter);
}
```

Here is a simple dummy program which shows the issue. As you see, the code of the two `bind` functions is (looks) exactly the same. Of course it is not, since two different functions (`addField`) are used, which only happen to share the name.

Nonetheless, I have been looking for a way to remove the need to verbatim write the `void bind(Presenter& p) const`.

Does anyone see a method for reaching the goal? I wasn't able to come up with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate to a template that can be called with a const or a non-const instance of `Presented`:

```
class Presented{
public:
    Presented() : a(0), b(0.) {}
    void bind(Presenter& p){
        bindImpl(p, *this);

    }
    void bind(Presenter& p) const {
        bindImpl(p, *this);
    }
private:
    template<typename P>
    static void bindImpl(Presenter& p, P& presented)
    {
        p.addField(presented.a);
        p.addField(presented.b);
    }

    int a;
    double b;
};
```

Comment: static... I was quite there, but I didn't manage to think of making it static. Thank you very much!